# WebClient Does Not Return PHPSESSID

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I have a CookieAwareWebClient

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;

        }
        return request;
    }

}
```

I am using this class to log into webpages and its working fine. I want to get the cookie value and show it inside GUI. Cookie value I got from browser is

> PHPSESSID=8m3vbs6bpt8utj7st64qe9nvd5; security=low

However when I request the cookie inside the program;

```
client.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];
```

returns "security=low"

How do I get PHPSESSID as well ? Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe the PHPSESSID wasn't even set in that case?

Comment: @addy2012 Yes, PHPSESSID doesnt exist under any cookie header. Is it only used with browsers?